# Does the Google Directions API use UTC or Local Time?

Tags: google-maps

I am developing a transit navigation app using the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions).

The API requires me to submit a departure time (`departure_time`) for transit queries.

Is it necessary to convert the local time to UTC time for this parameter?

I could not validate it through the API's response, as there is no accurate time returned in it.

Comment: I tested it in both NYC and Shanghai.
It seems that the API works right only with the local time zone.

Answer (score 2):

### That Doc Was In Error

Apparently the Google team writing [that doc page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#ExampleRequests) made an error and later fixed it.

The number you report `1343605500` is no longer found on that page. Today the number on that page is `1343641500`. I suspect you did indeed see that number on that page previously. Googling (ironically enough) for `site:https://developers.google.com  1343605500` does list that page as a hit. Apparently the hit is based on a cached copy of the old erroneous page. Even Google cannot escape the reach of Google.

### Work in UTC/GMT

> Is it necessary to convert the local time to UTC time for this parameter?

Yes.

The API works with GMT/UTC (no time zone offset), which only makes sense when you think about it. Almost always, the best practice for handling date-time is to perform your business logic, serialization, database records, and so on in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), then convert to local time only for presentation to the user.

Just looking at the example URL itself suggests it is in UTC. The only possible reference to a local time zone would be the word "Brooklyn" which is certainly not a clear unique identifier for a time zone.

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&sensor=false&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit

And of course the doc says the API uses UTC/GMT:

> the desired time of departure as seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC

### Poor Writing

The  confusion stems from the poor writing in that [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#ExampleRequests). They need to append a crucial "UTC" or "GMT" to that "9:45 am". Mentioning New York and 9:45 in the same breath implies local time, whereas that example is truly 5:45 in the morning local time in Brooklyn.

> The below request searches for Transit Directions from Brooklyn, New York to Queens, New York. When requesting transit directions, be sure to specify either a departure_time or arrival_time.
>
> Note that in this example the departure time is specified as July 30, 2012 at 09:45 am. Update the parameter to a point in the future before submitting the request.

### Old Versus New Numbers

Old number: 1343605500 (reported in the [answer by davidg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626199/642706), and by googling)

New number: 1343641500 (found 2013-12)

Number if they had actually meant 9:45 in New York: 1343655900.

### Example Code

I don't do JavaScript. So instead, I present some Java code using the sophisticated [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) 2.3 date-time handling library running in Java 7. I use both the old (erroneous) and new (correct) numbers to show the date-time in both UTC and New York time zones. Furthermore, I calculate the number of seconds since epoch would have been used to get to 9:45 am July 30 2012 in New York, to produce a third number of seconds.

The Google API uses seconds, while Joda-Time uses milliseconds, so I multiply or divide by a thousand.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone_NewYork = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );

// On this page:
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#ExampleRequests
// …look for the following two paragraphs…
// --
// The below request searches for Transit Directions from Brooklyn, New York to Queens, New York. When requesting transit directions, be sure to specify either a departure_time or arrival_time.
// Note that in this example the departure time is specified as July 30, 2012 at 09:45 am. Update the parameter to a point in the future before submitting the request.
// --
// Below that text, find this URL:
// http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&sensor=false&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit
// Extract that departure time of 1,343,641,500 seconds since the Unix Epoch of beginning of 1970 UTC.
// Apparently in the past that page erroneously used the number 1343605500 where today it uses 1343641500.

// Use the correct number found on that page today, 2013-12-25: 1343641500.
DateTime dateTimeInUtcWithNewNumber = new DateTime ( ( 1343641500L * 1000L ), DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeInNewYorkWithNewNumber = dateTimeInUtcWithNewNumber.toDateTime( timeZone_NewYork );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInUtcWithNewNumber: " + dateTimeInUtcWithNewNumber );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInNewYorkWithNewNumber: " + dateTimeInNewYorkWithNewNumber );

// Use the old erroneous number previously found on that page: 1343605500.
DateTime dateTimeInUtcWithOldNumber = new DateTime ( ( 1343605500L * 1000L ), DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeInNewYorkWithOldNumber = dateTimeInUtcWithOldNumber.toDateTime( timeZone_NewYork );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInUtcWithOldNumber: " + dateTimeInUtcWithOldNumber );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInNewYorkWithOldNumber: " + dateTimeInNewYorkWithOldNumber );

// Calculating the number that should have been used if the Google team had actually meant 9:45 AM local time in New York: 1343655900.
DateTime dateTimeInNewYork_2012_07_30_09_45 = new DateTime ( 2012, 7, 30, 9, 45, 0, timeZone_NewYork );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInNewYork_2012_07_30_09_45: " + dateTimeInNewYork_2012_07_30_09_45 );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInNewYork_2012_07_30_09_45 in seconds since Unix epoch: " + ( dateTimeInNewYork_2012_07_30_09_45.getMillis() / 1000L ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeInUtcWithNewNumber: 2012-07-30T09:45:00.000Z
dateTimeInNewYorkWithNewNumber: 2012-07-30T05:45:00.000-04:00
dateTimeInUtcWithOldNumber: 2012-07-29T23:45:00.000Z
dateTimeInNewYorkWithOldNumber: 2012-07-29T19:45:00.000-04:00
dateTimeInNewYork_2012_07_30_09_45: 2012-07-30T09:45:00.000-04:00
dateTimeInNewYork_2012_07_30_09_45 in seconds since Unix epoch: 1343655900
```

Comment: I have forgotten this question for ten years until the StackOverflow notify me.  Thank you for the detailed answer.