# Explaination of time format (Google Directions API)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, time, google-directions-api

I have read the documentation of the Google Directions API for making a direction request. An example of a URL is given as

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&sensor=false&departure_time=1343605500&mode=transit
```

The value of the `departure_time` variable is supposed to reflect the following information:

July 30, 2012 at 09:45 am.

Can someone please explain this time format.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation in question? That doc may be flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a timestamp - seconds elapsed since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number), 1970-01-01 00:00:00 [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). If you want "right now" in that format, you can use `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000`, or if you have a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, you can use `date.getTime() / 1000`.

Comment: @RaghavSood it isn't, actually. 1343605500 millis from the epoch is 1970-01-16 13:13:25 UTC.

Comment: @gustafc  While this answer is correct in concept, it is wrong in fact. The departure time of 1343605500 seconds since Unix Epoch does *not* equal July 30, 2012 at 09:45 am in either New York or UTC. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20698586/642706). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn't see your comment until now, five years later. I did some sleuthing and I have to correct you :) You're right that the timestamp is 2012-07-30 09:45 neither in UTC nor in New York time, but the docs didn't mention time zones. Some experimentation shows that the timestamp is exactly `2012-07-30T09:45+10:00`, but why use UTC+10? According to Wikipedia, the company that later became Google Maps was located in Sydney, which uses the AEST timezone, which is... UTC+10!

Answer (score 1):

That's an epoch unix timestamp (number of seconds since Jan 1 1970). You can create a date by

```
Date d = new Date(1343605500L);
```

Or use http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

### Flaw In Google Documentation

Googling for that particular number led to places such as [this similar StackOverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12515539/642706). These pages lead me to conclude that the documentation for Google Directions API is flawed.

You and others report that the doc says 1343605500 = July 30, 2012 at 09:45 am in New York. But that is incorrect. Both the day of month and the hour of day are wrong.

`1343605500` seconds from the beginning of the year 1970 UTC/GMT:

- In New York is `2012-07-29T19:45:00.000-04:00`
- In UTC/GMT is `2012-07-29T23:45:00.000Z`

---

### Getting Date-Time From A Number

As the other answers stated, apparently Google is handing you the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch at the beginning of the year 1970 in UTC/GMT (no time zone offset).

Alternatively to using java.util.Date/Calendar classes, you can use the third-party open-source [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Here is some example source code to show you how to parse the text into a date-time with time zone.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

// Starting data.
String string = "1343605500";
String timeZoneName = "America/New_York";

// Convert string of seconds to number of milliseconds.
long millis = Long.parseLong( string ) * 1000 ; //
// Specify time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( timeZoneName );
// Instantiate DateTime object.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( millis, timeZone );

System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTime in UTC/GMT: " + dateTime.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2012-07-29T19:45:00.000-04:00
dateTime in UTC/GMT: 2012-07-29T23:45:00.000Z
```

When using a count from epoch, you must be careful about:

- Which epoch (Unix Time is but one of several possibilities)
- Precision of count (seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds)

[image: Diagram of precision of time since epoch, with POSIX Unix time using seconds, java.util.Date and Joda-time using milliseconds, and JSR 310 java.time.* classes using nanoseconds]