# timestamp in google calculate directions api in c#

Tags: c#, google-maps, geospatial, unix-timestamp, utc

I am trying to get the directions for the future time using Google Calculate Directions API [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). I want to enter the specific timestamp and I see that we have to enter the

> time in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC

. I am confused on how to convert the required time in the required time zone as an integer specified. For example, I want to enter 24th August 2019 08 AM PDT timestamp for the API, how should I convert this to the required input format. I searched online and different websites are giving me different answers.

The answers given shows the javascript way of obtaining the value, however, I am looking to implement it in c#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: In JavaScript you can do `new Date('August 24 2019 08:00:00').getTime()`. Also see this SO question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/15620486/11742502

Comment: I also recommend using the [Directions Calculator](https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/).

Comment: @evan, Can you tell me how do we calculate this in c#

Comment: Sure! I believe there are multiple ways to do this in c#, see  https://stackoverflow.com/q/17632584/11742502 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49248822/11742502

Comment: just did a quick search, there are likely more

Comment: Yeah!! I got it. There's actually a method 'ToUnixTimeSeconds' in c#

Comment: Glad to hear! :)